# No puedo guardar un video desde el form que yo hice en django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

Hice una copia sencilla de youtube con django y funciona bien, el único problema es que el formulario que yo hice para que el usuario pueda subir videos no me guarda los videos.
Toda la información como el titulo o la descripción si queda registrada, pero el video no.
Si lo hago desde el admin si puedo subir videos correctamente y no se que pueda ser.
Muchas gracias por la ayuda

> views.py #Video

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Video

@login_required
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        title = request.POST.get('title')
        description = request.POST.get('description')
        fileMedia = request.POST.get('fileMedia')
        user = request.user
        video = Video(title=title, description=description, user=user, media=fileMedia)
        video.save()
        return redirect('/')
    return render(request, "templatesBase/upload.html")
```

> models.py #video

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

```
class Video(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=False)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    media = models.FileField(upload_to="static/videos/media_upload", max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title} ({self.user.username})'
```

> upload.html

```
<form action="" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Titulo del video</label>
        <input name="title" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Descripcion</label>
        <textarea name="description" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Seleccionar video</label>
        <input name="fileMedia" type="file" accept="video/*" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1">
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Subir</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Agregando esto a tu formulario en el template deberia funcionar si la vista guarda correctamente el video:

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
</form>
```

Igualmente lo que yo haria para escribir lo menos html posible y hacerlo mas a lo django way seria crear un django model form asi:

forms.py

```
from django import forms

from .models import Video


class VideoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = "__all__"
        model = Video
```

luego en la vista lo usaria asi:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from .forms import VideoForm
from .models import Video


@login_required
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = VideoForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = VideoForm()
    context = {"form": form}
    return render(request, "templatesBase/upload.html", context)
```

y en el template:

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Luego si queres agregar bootstrap 4 a tus formularios podes usar esto: https://pypi.org/project/django-bootstrap4/.